# Over-ride or don't log the page an event occurs on

Tags: google-analytics

I've just began using the powerful event tracking code on one of my projects to monitor when certain things happen. Unfortunately, in this case, it's logging the page which the event happens on.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Is it possible to over-ride the page that is logged against the event. For example a user might be searching for "hardcore porn" and the url will be /?q=hardcore+porn and the event will be logged against that page. So when I look at the top pages on which events happen, this will be visible. Ideally I'd like to log the pageview for all these events as just "/" and not log the sensitive search queries.

I should note that it's not logging these pages as pageviews, but pages that events happen on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are tracking site search in GA**, you can set up the profile to [strip the query parameter from the search](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_id=ad&answer=1012264):

> Select whether or not you want Google Analytics to strip the query parameter from your URL.
>   Note that this strips only the parameters you provided, and not any other parameters in the same URL. This has the same functionality as excluding URL Query Parameters in your Main Profile: if you strip the query parameters from your Site Search Profile, you don't have to exclude them again from your Main Profile.

Go to `Profile Settings`, `Site Search Settings`, and check `Strip query parameters out of URL`

**If you are not tracking site search**, you can exclude specific URL params. Go to `Profile Settings`, `General Information`, and put the URL params in the box for `Exclude URL Query Parameters`.